# Invalid content type when Sendgrid as SMTP Relay Server for Firebase Authentication Email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sendgrid

I'm configuring Sendgrid as SMTP for Firebase Authentication Email but when I try to send an email the server sends it with content-type: text/plain

[image]

So the HTML content is not recognized when the user receives it

[image]

When default SMTP Firebase service sends the email with Content-Type: multipart/alternative the html content is recognized

Current Firebase SMTP configuration

I have looked into the SendGrid documentation but I did not find useful resources for fix this.

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: How are you sending the email from Firebase?

Comment: From GCP -> Identity Platform -> Users -> Reset Password

Comment: This is weird, SendGrid is happy to send HTML emails with the correct MIME type. If these emails are being sent from within the Firebase admin, then it's likely an issue on the Firebase side. I don't think I can help here, you might need to wait for someone with more Firebase experience to answer, or contact Firebase support.